# Как происходит хеширование буффера?

Tags: node.js, sha256, buffer

Имеется хеш из 32 символов `var hex = 'c5bf72e887242098655ab4f3bdeee997';`, из него создается буфер
`new Buffer(hex, 'hex')`, как я понимаю буфер по сути, это тоже самое что и `hex.match(/.{1,2}/g)`

Далее делаем

```
crypto.createHash('sha256')
    .update(hexBuffer)
    .digest();
```

Если загонять в sha256 обычный hex, получаются отличимые от sha256(hexBuffer) данные. Чем преобразование буфера в sha256 отличимо от преобразования string в sha256?

**UPD**

Уточню, что имеется ввиду, загоняя, исходный текст в виде буффера(hex), я получаю:

```
df9c65fa98b3d31e8e2548ed3b7c383338275705545eaabf560a619372a433ec
```

Но загоняя исходный в виде обычного текста на выходе получается

```
43c0e15148c1b1b9e7253f940081f4740d2f3c74c408c8ae8a4d704a7d4f21e5
```

Чем отличаются 2 данных преобразования?

А задача моя используя библиотеку sjcl sha256 (если это возможно), получить из hex такой же ответ, как получаю в первом примере выше. Но буфер как входные данные он не принимает

Comment: Очевидно, тем, что строка и буфер содержат очевидно разные данные, значит и хеш в итоге должен получаться разный. А зачем вы вообще хешируете хеш?

Comment: «буфер по сути, это тоже самое» — нет. У вас написано что-то непонятное…

Comment: @andreymal Для получения мнемоники из hex энтропии у bitcoin

Comment: Когда вы используете буфер вы хеширует байты `c5 bf 72 ...` (см мой ответ), когда вы используете строку, вы на самом деле используете `Buffer.from(строка, 'utf8')` и хешируете совсем другие байтики (`63 35 62 ...`)

Comment: @AlexeyTen все понял теперь. благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже проблема в непонимании что такое [`Buffer` в Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Если совсем просто, `Buffer` это набор байтов.

```js
var hex = 'c5bf72e887242098655ab4f3bdeee997';
var hexBuffer = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex');
```

Теперь в `hexBuffer` лежит 16 байт. Например `hexBuffer[0] === 197` или, то же самое, `hexBuffer[0] === 0xc5`.

Перейдём к хешу. [`hash.update`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding) принимает два параметра, собственно данные и «кодировка» в которой они записаны. Кодировка по умолчанию `'utf8'`. Но кодировка нужна только для того, что бы преобразовать строку в `Buffer`, так что если первый параметр это уже буфер, то второй параметр не нужен.

Поэтому следующие строки дают одинаковый результат:

```js
hash.update(hexBuffer)
hash.update(Buffer.from(hex, 'hex'))
hash.update(hex, 'hex')
```

вы же не передали второй параметр, что эквивалентно `hash.update(hex, 'utf8')` и конечно результат получается другой. Потому что по сути вы передали другие данные:

```js
Buffer.from(hex, 'hex')
// <Buffer c5 bf 72 e8 87 24 20 98 65 5a b4 f3 bd ee e9 97>
Buffer.from(hex, 'utf8')
// <Buffer 63 35 62 66 37 32 65 38 38 37 32 34 32 30 39 38 36 35 35 61 62 34 66 33 62 64 65 65 65 39 39 37>
```

Comment: Тут скорее самая большая моя проблема, в формулировке, для хеширования буфера, да используется  Buffer.from(hex, 'hex').  И вот я не понимаю как работает само хеширование в случае hex буфера в отличии от хеширования в случае hex string. 
Потому что загоняя, буфер я получаю одно, а загоняя этот же текст, но в виде string, другое.